# Use Value from One Column in Another Column

Tags: calculated-columns, obiee

In Oracle BI Answers, I am on the Criteria tab and added a column with a complicated formula.  Let's call this column c9.  I would like to add another column which has a formula.  This formula uses the value from column c9.  How is this done?

In other words, can we associate an explicit alias and use it in criteria?  Or can we save a column and reference a saved column definition in another one?

Answer (score 0):

There is a droppdown called Column in the Column Formula dialog box. Just select the column you want.

For example, I created a column "Really Complex Formula" as "Allowance Rate + 1".

I selected that column (the name that I gave it), and it pulls in the entire formula.

[image]

Comment: I am aware of this.  I am trying to avoid pulling in the complex formula.  I am going to use the computed column in several places in a complex formula.  Using the formula would make for a very large and difficult formula.

Comment: What OBIEE version are you on? Version 11.1.1.9 and later allow you to create and save a column back to the catalog. I am on 11.1.1.7 so I cant show this feature.

Comment: I am on OBIEE version 12.2.1.0.0.  I tried creating and saving a column back to the catalog.  Unfortunately, using the saved column pulls in the complex formula.

Comment: Interesting. I would open an SR with oracle, and once you get an answer post it here!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible in "Oracle Business Intelligence 11.1.1.7.150120" Version other I have not tested. when you are in Criteria tab you will find a column option from there you can select any column and in criteria column you will see obiee will use a column count as alias. I have attached a screen shot for better understanding. this will work in union Reports.for other reports you need to create logical alias in your table for columns.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOQEP.gif)